# .Net 1.1 Web Service Client Basic Authentication

Tags: .net

I'm trying to call a web service from a .Net 1.1 application. The Web Service uses Basic Authentication. For some reason the "Authorization" header attribute is not set. Here's the code that I think should do the trick, but isn't.

```
        CredentialCache credCache = new CredentialCache();
        NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
        credCache.Add( new Uri(item.Url), "Basic", netCred);
        item.Credentials = credCache;
        item.PreAuthenticate = true;
        item.getAccountRequest(getRequest);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually working. The problem was else where in the code.